# Changing z-index of a program

Tags: windows, z-index

Is there any way for me 2 be able to change the z-index of a program which I downloaded, so it's always on top of whatever is on my screen? Currently it's pre-programmed to be on top of everything, but once I start a full-screen game, it's not on top anymore.

Ps: It's running on Windows 7 (64bit), & it's downloaded here: [code.google.com/...](https://code.google.com/p/twitch-irc-chat-overlay-txt-output/)
I'd try 2 figure it out from the code but I can't seem to find it, I thought programs on code.google.com are opensource, appearantly not.

Comment: You should at least specify the OS you are trying this on...

Answer (score 0):

No, the point of 'full screen' is 'full screen'. Once a game takes full screen control, usually via DirectX or OpenGL, they've taken over the 'hardware output context', not allowing any more games on top of them.

Many games have the option to run 'windowed' in their video options. That forces the game to remain in regular desktop drawing (at a performance cost) and as such allow interaction with the other windows in the desktop window manager.

Comment: Well, I believe this program actually taps into OpenGL or DirectX, but I'm not entirely sure, untill I figure it out, I suppose I'll have to run windowed QQ